# How I can write CSS for IE. My code not work in IE10 nor 9,7,8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have seen that the code I have is broken in IE. I tried it on IE9 and 8 and it works after writing some additional CSS to my pages.

Unfortunately I found that my IE hack is not working for version 10 that was launched recently. I go with http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/ but it's not working for now. I am testing it on windows 7 IE10.

For old IE I have written code like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Do someone have any trick for IE10. I have seen that IE10 work fine if I add this to my stylesheet. Now I want to know how to add Ie.css in IE10 browser.

Remember that IE10 is no longer support IE comments.
using Ie.css my code work in all browser except version 10.

Comment: Did you read http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/ ?

Comment: yes. this code not work for now.

Comment: Do you have a piece of code of your integration ?

Comment: yes, http://f1beta.com/test/

Comment: I do not see your JS like on the site I linked.

Comment: I have removed it because this is not working one min, I will upload it again.

Comment: Did you try my first proposition in my answer? The @media trick? It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS, this condition works for me:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10-specific styles go here */  
}
```

In JS, the same, it works for me:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--<script>  
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {  
    document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';  
}  
</script><!--<![endif]-->

.ie10 .example {  
   /* IE10-only styles go here */  
}
```

Source: http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/

Comment: Franscois, I got a another thing if I removed the conditional thing it's only add IE10 to Ie10. wow work fine without comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good! Think to vote up it my answers help you a little bit. :)